# Jquery updating array entry with specific results

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a form that has some pre populated fields. The data and ID values for these fields are pulled from a database.

The user has the option to add, edit or delete the rows, and the save the results. To save pushing numerous values back I'm adding to an array only the entries that have changed, are new or are marked to be deleted and then sending those back to my php page.

The form fields look like this :

```
  <tr>
        <td>
        <input name='id[]' type='hidden' value='123456789'/>
        <input name="site[]" type="text" value='123'/>
        </td>
        <td><input name="location[]" type="text" value='NW'/></td>
        <td><a href='#' name="deleteRow"/>x</td>
    </tr>
```

The array is called `rows[]` and looks like this: "mode:ID:A:B"

```
["del:123456789:0:0", "del:99887766:0:0", "edit:1471872633890:8845:0", "add:4875125862:1523:NE"]
```

If a user marks a row for deletion an entry similar to this is added to the array:

```
"del:99887766:0:0"
```

If the user adds a new row an entry similar to this is added to the array:

```
"add:1471938503:0:0"
```

and if an entry is edited the entry add to the array looks like:

```
"edit:1471872633890:8845:0"
```

This all seems to work upto a point..

When a user edits an entry I'm using the following to check the array and update the array entry where an ID matches. So if they edit the same value multiple times there is only one copy in the array.

```
var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="id[]"]').val()
var site = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="number[]"]').val()
var location = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[name="description[]"]').val()
var res = 'edit:' + id + ':' + site + ':' + location;

rows = rows.map(function(value) {
if( value.indexOf(id) > -1 ) {
    return res;
}
    return value;
});

if ($.inArray(res, rows) == -1) {
    rows.push(res)
}
```

Again this seems to work, but I have an issue..
When a new row is added, an entry is added to the array as: `"add:1471938503:0:0"`  but when the user then edits it, the entry changes to have the mode of `edit`  NOT `add`

How can I code this so a new entry has the mode of `add` and stays as `add` even if it is edited.  A `del` stays as `del`  and a `edit` stays as `edit`

I have tried :

```
var res = 'edit:' + id + ':' + site + ':' + location;
var resAdd = 'add:' + id + ':' + site + ':' + location;
rows = rows.map(function(value) {
        if( value.indexOf('add:'+id) > -1 ) {
            return resAdd;
        } else {
            return resEdit;
        }
            return value;
        });
```

But that just messed everything up !!

Any ideas how I can do this ?
I have created a **[codepen](http://codepen.io/Tom_T/pen/WxBzEd)**.. but it doesn't seem to want to run..

Thanks

Comment: I would create 3 arrays, one for each type of operation so that you don't run into the issue of an add becoming an edit. And just before submitting the whole thing, I would combine them then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this in your `map` function an prepend the correct action in front of `res`.

```
var res = ':' + id + ':' + site + ':' + location;

rows = rows.map(function(value) {
    if( value.indexOf(id) > -1 ) {
        return (value.indexOf('add') === 0 ? 'add' : 'edit') + res;
    }

    return value;
});
```

Or even possible to check with `substr`:

```
return (value.subtr(0, 3) === 'add' ? 'add' : 'edit') + res;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This sort of works.  When the user firsts loads the page the array is empty. So the first edit adds the entry to the array. That is done using 
`if ($.inArray(res, rows) == -1) {
    rows.push(res)
}`

Any further edits of that row are updated.  But using the new code the first entry added to the array is missing `edit` so I end up with duplicates. Please see my original post for the code being used to add the original entry to the array.

Thanks

Comment: Just prepend `edit` where you need it?! Like `if($.inArray('edit' + res, rows) == -1) { rows.push('edit' + res) }`. That should do the trick. @Tom

Comment: Thanks that works for editing. But adding a new row results in an entry being added to the array as `["add:1471952790023:0:0"]` but when you edit it you get `["add:1471952790023:sd:sd", "edit:1471952790023:sd:sd"]`  they are both being updated.. any ideas ?

Comment: In the above example, there shouldn't be an edit entry for `1471952790023`  just the add.

Comment: Think I may have go this working.. by changing the `$.inArray` to ` if ( ($.inArray('edit' + res, rows) == -1  && $.inArray('add' + res, rows) == -1)   ) {
   rows.push('edit' + res)
  }`

Not pretty but seems to work !